# How to load a csv file into a database when the filename for the CSV changes everyday

Tags: sql-loader

Trying to load a `.csv` into a database using SQL loader but The filename is changing every day but will always start with `health_safety`.

Here is the control file, it loads the data but I need to put in a specific file name, so if the filename changes, it breaks.

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE "\\ALI.PRI\Files\Apps\CRIS\test\Trents tests\Cris Too Tidal Job\HEALTH_SAFETY\health_safety345.csv"
INTO TABLE CRIS.CRIS_HEALTH_SAFETY_DATA
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
REPORTING_PERIOD,
PROJECT_ID,
VENDOR_ID,
HEALTH_SAFETY_ID,
HEALTH_SAFETY_ACTUAL,
HEALTH_SAFETY_DATE
)
```

Comment: Please post code as text rather than as image!

Comment: I did but the format gets messed up

Comment: @Trent try using ``` code here ```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version of Oracle you are on, but if you are on 12c the infile clause now supports wildcard characters.

If you are lucky, you could use:

```
INFILE "\\ALI.PRI\Files\...\health_safety*.csv"
```

Otherwise, you'll need a wrapper script that passes the filename in using the DATA argument. Do a little searching here, there are examples.